# Get auto-incremented id(primary key) from Oracle Database through Spring MVC

Tags: java, oracle, spring-mvc

I am using Triggers to make the id column of a table auto-increment by itself in the Oracle database.

Here is the code in my Spring controller,

```
@RequestMapping("/ssuForm/create")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public UmkeiBusinessInfo createSsuForm(@RequestBody UmkeiBusinessInfo umkeiSsu) {

    UmkeiBusinessInfo createSsuForm = umkeiBusinessInfoService.create(umkeiSsu);
    System.out.println(createSsuForm);
    return createSsuForm;
}
```

How upon using the System.out.println to see what was returned, I cannot see the id being listed. Everything else did though.

Here the log,

```
|Nexus|Wed Apr 13 00:00:00 SGT 2016|Nexus Street|NexusCity|04|null|80000|0108808550|nexus@nexi.com|1|A|2|P1|B10A218|Sun Apr 03 10:40:28 SGT 2016|null||B10A218|1|0145283459|teniousd@yahoo.com|9|A08|00751A|null|null|null|null|null
```

Notice it starts with the Nexus, not the ID.

Below is the snippet of what my table looks like,
[image]

EDIT:

This is the code inside /business/service/impl

```
    @Override
public UmkeiBusinessInfo save(UmkeiBusinessInfo umkeiBusinessInfo) {
    return update(umkeiBusinessInfo) ;
}

@Override
public UmkeiBusinessInfo create(UmkeiBusinessInfo umkeiBusinessInfo) {
    UmkeiBusinessInfoEntity umkeiBusinessInfoEntity = umkeiBusinessInfoJpaRepository.findOne(umkeiBusinessInfo.getUbiId());
    if( umkeiBusinessInfoEntity != null ) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("already.exists");
    }
    umkeiBusinessInfoEntity = new UmkeiBusinessInfoEntity();
    umkeiBusinessInfoServiceMapper.mapUmkeiBusinessInfoToUmkeiBusinessInfoEntity(umkeiBusinessInfo, umkeiBusinessInfoEntity);
    UmkeiBusinessInfoEntity umkeiBusinessInfoEntitySaved = umkeiBusinessInfoJpaRepository.save(umkeiBusinessInfoEntity);
    return umkeiBusinessInfoServiceMapper.mapUmkeiBusinessInfoEntityToUmkeiBusinessInfo(umkeiBusinessInfoEntitySaved);
}

@Override
public UmkeiBusinessInfo update(UmkeiBusinessInfo umkeiBusinessInfo) {
    UmkeiBusinessInfoEntity umkeiBusinessInfoEntity = umkeiBusinessInfoJpaRepository.findOne(umkeiBusinessInfo.getUbiId());
    umkeiBusinessInfoServiceMapper.mapUmkeiBusinessInfoToUmkeiBusinessInfoEntity(umkeiBusinessInfo, umkeiBusinessInfoEntity);
    UmkeiBusinessInfoEntity umkeiBusinessInfoEntitySaved = umkeiBusinessInfoJpaRepository.save(umkeiBusinessInfoEntity);
    return umkeiBusinessInfoServiceMapper.mapUmkeiBusinessInfoEntityToUmkeiBusinessInfo(umkeiBusinessInfoEntitySaved);
}
```

and here is the entity part,

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// ENTITY PRIMARY KEY ( BASED ON A SINGLE FIELD )
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
@NotNull
@Size( min = 1, max = 20 )
private String ubiId;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// ENTITY DATA FIELDS 
//----------------------------------------------------------------------    
@Size( max = 100 )
private String ubiName;


private Date ubiStartDate;

@Size( max = 100 )
private String ubiAddress;

@Size( max = 64 )
private String ubiCity;

@Size( max = 10 )
private String ubiState;

@Size( max = 10 )
private String ubiCountry;
```

and here is the JPA entity part,

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// ENTITY PRIMARY KEY ( BASED ON A SINGLE FIELD )
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
@Id
@Column(name="UBI_ID", nullable=false, length=20)
private String     ubiId        ;


//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// ENTITY DATA FIELDS 
//----------------------------------------------------------------------    
@Column(name="UBI_NAME", length=100)
private String     ubiName      ;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="UBI_START_DATE")
private Date       ubiStartDate ;

@Column(name="UBI_ADDRESS", length=100)
private String     ubiAddress   ;
```

Comment: Why in the world would you use a trigger to increment the id and not use a native sequencer?

Comment: Oops sorry, I enabled the trigger and it activates the Sequence automatically. I did nothing after I enabled the Trigger.

Comment: Can you please post the pieces of code where you save/update the data and Entity if you're using JPA

Comment: @Bunti I have updated the question. Hope I included what you need to know.

Comment: You seem to be missing [@GeneratedValue](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html) with `strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE` and the name of your sequence generator.

Comment: I got this error, Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown Id.generator: UMKEI_BUSINESS_INFO_SEQ1
Where the name is there in my table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got it working.

First I need to change the datatype to 'Number' in ORACLE, then change all of the codes from String to BigDecimal.

Then add the annotations like Bunti mentioned,

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="UMKEI_BUSINESS_INFO_SEQ1")
@SequenceGenerator(name="UMKEI_BUSINESS_INFO_SEQ1 ", sequenceName="UMKEI_BUSINESS_INFO_SEQ1", allocationSize=1)
```

and I got my incremental value passed to the client.

Previously it wasn't working because of the dataType.